# Sum values from different dataframes

Tags: python, group-by, conditional-statements

I have the following dataframes:

```
print(X)

Quantity   Class    
   1         0
   5         0
   6         1
   8         2
   9         3
   0         4
...

print(dframe)

   Pred_class    Delta
           0  -0.046348
           1   1.856508
           2  20.347518
           3  -7.138728
           4   6.642686
```

I would like to create an additional columns to X - "Final_Q" - sum of X["Quantity"] and the corresponding "Delta", **for each class**:

print(X)

```
Quantity   Class    Final_Q  
   1         0        1 - (-0.046348) 
   5         0        5 - (-0.046348)
   6         1        6 - (+1.856508)
...
```

I tried with:

```
for i in np.unique(X["Class"]):

        #Isolate     
        X["Class"] == i
        dframe["Pred_class"] == i

        X_test_virtuale["BOOST"] = X_test_virtuale["ALG_N_forecast"] - dframe.iloc[0,0]
```

But it does not seem to work properly;

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, first you want to merge:

```
 X = X.merge(dframe, how='left', left_on='Class', right_on='Pred_class')
```

and then you want to just add as normal:

```
 X['Final_Q'] = X['Quantity'] + X['Delta']
```

which will get you this:

```
   Class  Quantity      Delta  Pred_class    Final_Q
0      0         1  -0.046348           0   0.953652
1      0         5  -0.046348           0   4.953652
2      1         6   1.856508           1   7.856508
3      2         8  20.347518           2  28.347518
4      3         9  -7.138728           3   1.861272
5      4         0   6.642686           4   6.642686
```

Comment: it should be "- X['Delta']" instead of "+"; the rest works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

You can use a pandas merge_asof once you rename `Pred_class` as below.

`dframe = dframe.rename(columns={'Pred_class':'Class'})
s = pd.merge_asof(X, dframe, on='Class')
s['FinalQ'] = s['Quantity'] - s['Class']`

`Index Quantity  Class  Delta  FinalQ
0         1      0  -0.04       1
1         5      0  -0.04       5
2         6      1   1.90       5
3         8      2  20.30       6
4         9      3  -7.00       6
5         0      4   6.60      -4`